# Don't know how to preprocess my dataset for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Im trying to do image classification using CNN. The exact model isn't important but I decided to try use AlexNet and im getting abysmal accuracy. 
[The picture of my model accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT15I.png)

I believe the issue may be with my data preprocessing. 
My dataset directory contains a Training and Test folder (no validation folder) and they are layed out like this:

```
Training
├── class0
│   ├── image1
│   ├── ....
│   └── image20
│
├── ....
│   ├── image1
│   ├── ....
│   └── image20
│
└── class9
    ├── image1
    ├── ....
    └── image20
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
train_dir = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/x/Training'
test_dir = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/x/Test'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest',
      )

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.4)

# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(224, 224),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=20,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

# Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary',
        subset='validation')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,  # 2000 images = batch_size * steps
      epochs=10,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=10,  # 1000 images = batch_size * steps
      #callbacks = [checkpoint],
      verbose=2)
```

I'm fairly certain its not my AlexNet model thats the issue but if it actually is, the code is below:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    #Conv_1          #original model was built for input shape of 224X224
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(96, (11,11),strides=4, padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    # Pooling_1
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2),padding='valid'),
    # Batch Normalisation_1
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    # Conv_2
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (11,11),strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    # Pooling_2
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2),padding='valid'),
    #Batch Normalisation_2
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    # Conv_3
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(384, (3,3),strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    # Batch Normalisation_3
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    # Conv_4
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(384, (3,3),strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    # Batch Normalisation_3
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    #conv_5
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    #pooling_3
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2),padding='valid'),
    #Batch Normalization_4
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    #Dense layer_1
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    #Dense layer_2
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    #Dense layer_3
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

Sorry for the long post and I will be extremely grateful for any help!

Comment: This question belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com or https://datascience.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will post my question there. I'll leave this question here in case anyone on stackoverflow can solve it though.